# Applying Spree decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

H guys, first of all let me tell u I am new to spree, so my question might sound stupid to most of you. I want to customize for example the "index" method in the home_controller.rb, I know the right way is to use a decorators. So I have created this file app/controller/home_controller_decorator.rb. I have in there

# app/controller/home_controller_decorator.rb

```
HomeController.class_eval do
  def index
    # Empty method
  end
end
```

The original spree index method looks like

```
def index
  @searcher = Spree::Config.searcher_class.new(params)
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
  respond_with(@products)
end
```

I expect that when I restart the server with the _decorator added it will display me no products on the home page, or will crash. When applying this decorator and starting the server I get this message

```
agop@linux-as2q:~/Desktop/spp> rails server -p 3000
/home/agop/Desktop/spp/app/controllers/home_controller_decorator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Spree::BaseController (NameError)
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/lib/spree_site.rb:5:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/lib/spree_site.rb:4:in `glob'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/lib/spree_site.rb:4:in `<class:Engine>'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/lib/spree_site.rb:2:in `<module:SpreeSite>'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/lib/spree_site.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/config/application.rb:11:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Spp>'
    from /home/agop/Desktop/spp/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am probably not writing the decorator in the way spree expects. What is the correct way to apply this decorator on the home_controller.rb index method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `HomeController` inherits from `Spree::BaseController` which isn't loaded at this point in time due to some unknown reason. You should be able to fix it by putting `require 'spree/base_controller'` at the top of your decorator.

Could you please also submit a GitHub issue for this on http://github.com/spree/spree? It would be helpful for anybody else who ran into this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

[ActiveSupport::Concern](http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/) is a clean way to decorate existing classes.

But note, that caches are not cached in development mode, so you'll need to add something like the code below in config/environments/development.rb to ensure that your decorate methods persist.

```
    config.to_prepare do
        #SomeModel.send(:include, SomeDecorator)
    end
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895103/how-can-i-keep-my-initializer-configuration-from-being-lost-in-development-mode) are more details on this.