# How can I keep my initializer configuration from being lost in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on a Rails app that uses an engine. I'm using an initializer to configure one of my engine's controllers so that it will trigger an action in the host app. The code looks something like this:

```
# config/initializers/my_engine.rb
MyEngine::SomeController.after_filter proc {
  # Do something in the host app
}, :only => :update
```

This works fine in production, but in development mode, the proc is only called on the first request. This is because the classes are getting reloaded and this configuration is lost, because it was stored in a class variable. (For example, `MyEngine::SomeController` is reloaded from the file it's in, and since the `after_filter` isn't declared there, it isn't added back on.)

#### Some Rails background

In development mode, Rails uses the following load strategy:

- Code in the `app` directory is reloaded on each request, on the assumption that you're actively changing it.
- Code in the `lib` directory, along with `config/initializer` files, are loaded **once**, when the application boots.

Initializer files are generally used for configuring gems. In the past, gems have mostly had code in the `lib` directory, so running their configuration once was sufficient.

#### How engines change things

However, Rails engines have code in the `app` directory: controllers, models, etc. These files are reloaded in development mode on each request. Therefore, configuration like my example above is lost.

#### Enter to_prepare

Rails provides `config.to_prepare` specifically to solve this problem: it run once in production, and on every request in development.

For example, we have this in application.rb, which works fine:

```
config.to_prepare do
  # set up class variables (after_filters, etc)
end
```

However, if I have to put all my engines' configuration in `application.rb`, this defeats the point of `config/initializers` in keeping things organized.

So, for any configuration of classes in my engines' `app` directories, I want to put that code in files under `config/initializers`.

Here are my questions.

- I'm unclear how to get `config` into scope in an initializer file. I'm thinking it would be `Rails.application.config`. Is that right?
- Can I add add multiple `to_prepare` blocks? I'm afraid that calling it multiple times will overwrite previous blocks.

### Update

As @Frederick Cheung mentioned, `Rails.application.config.to_prepare` does work in `config/initializer` files, and one can use as many of these as needed in the various files; each call appends its block to an array, so nothing is overwritten.

So **the solution to this problem** is:

```
# config/initializers/my_engine.rb
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  MyEngine::SomeController.after_filter proc {
    # Do something in the host app
  }, :only => :update
end
```

One thing that still seems odd: I expected the `to_prepare` block to be called on **every request** in development mode, but instead it seems to be called randomly every 3rd request or so. I added block:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Rails.logger.info "Running the prepare block!"
end
```

... restarted my app, and refreshed the page nine times. I only saw the message on the 1st, 5th, 7th and 9th requests. I'm not sure what explains this behavior, but it does explain why my code **without** the `to_prepare` worked intermittently in development.

Comment: The intermittence with which it runs could be due to using passenger in development with rails.  You are also using the smart rails reloader gem for speeding up assets which could also effect things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add as many `to_prepare` blocks as you want - when you do `config.to_prepare`, Rails is doing (in `configuration.rb` in railties)

```
def to_prepare(&blk)
  to_prepare_blocks << blk if blk
end
```

and then iterates over those blocks handing them over to `ActionDispatch::Reloader`, where `to_prepare` is implemented using `ActiveSupport::Callbacks` (i.e. the same thing that is used for `before_save` and so on). Multiple `to_prepare` blocks are fine.

Currently it looks like Rails iterates over `to_prepare_blocks` after reading application initialisers so adding to `Rails.application.configuration.to_prepare` should work. You may prefer to use `ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare`.

Comment: OK, I see that method. Specifically, it's in `rails/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to stop you from doing initializer code in a file that lives in app/models.

for example

```
class MyClass
  def self.run_me_when_the_class_is_loaded
  end
end

MyClass.run_me_when_the_class_is_loaded
```

MyClass.run_me... will run when the class is loaded .... which is what we want, right?

Not sure if its the Rails way.... but its extremely straightforward, and does not depend on the shifting winds of Rails.

Comment: It does seem to work, albeit a little haphazardly. Sometimes it gets called on server boot, and sometimes it is called on the fly. Using an initializer file ensures that the code will only execute on server boot.

Comment: Define "haphazard".   Also, loading via initializer doesn't work for the person asking the question.