# Rails development mode and initializers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a class in `./app/models/foo.rb` which is initialized in `./config/initializers/foo.rb`
with something like `Foo.items = YAML.load_file "foo.yml"`. When some other file is modified `foo.rb` is reloaded and items are lost obviously. What is the preferred way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Why do you seed data through an initializer? Why don't you just create a rake task for that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895103/how-can-i-keep-my-initializer-configuration-from-being-lost-in-development-mode#8896891).

Essentially, wrap your configuration in a to_prepare block:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Foo.items = YAML.load_file "foo.yml"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the exact scenario is that is happening, but here's a guess: does `Foo`'s definition initialize `items` with something empty? Perhaps don't do this.

It would help if you showed us some code.